# Zip file with .csv extention lost somewhere in filesystem

Tags: zip, file-search

The file is also locked with winzip and I cant remember the name or directory, I hid it in a very obscure directory. Could be in the windows system files could be in a program directory file. I did a search for all .CSV files I have 4-5K to go through. Any suggestions on how this could be done?

I was opening up files in batches by highlighting a bunch that pressing edit with notepad plus plus. Than going  through each one. I know once the file is opened in notepad plus it will not show any words. It is pictures. I own an eCommerce site and I have my master copies that I bought $X,XXX and did not want to take any chances in them be found and resold by other people on my network. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening any `zip` file in a hex editor suggests that every `zip` file starts with a data of `PK`. We can use it in our favour. :)

Download this software: [EditPad Pro](http://www.editpadpro.com/)

What this software does is, it recurses through the whole filesystem starting from a specified base folder to search for any string residing in any of the child files, they maybe Text or Binary, it treats them the same, thus giving accurate results.

In our case, it's a regex: `^PK`

When you'll execute this search, the software will return all the files that start with data `PK`, make sure you do a casesensitive search.

Comment: Awesome!! I have been trying to find this file for months off an on. Just tried it on a small scale on my laptop and it found my test file! now going to try on my server..

Comment: I think this will work as long as i start from the right start folder. What would check every single directory and file on the whole computer? I have no idea were it is.To bad this site didnt have a donate to user button!!

Comment: This software would check just anything in anynumber of folders. Just choose your base folder, then checkmark the option `Recurse through Subfolders`, all your Subfolders and their subfolders and their subfolders, so on.. will be checked for the string to exist. @Original-newbie

Comment: it wont let me says Vote Up requires 15 reputation

Comment: Choosing the right answer is different than Voting Up or Down. There must be an outlined Checkmark right under voting options. It says, **`click to set this answer as your accepted answer; click again to toggle`**, that's where you've to click to choose a correct answer. @Original-newbie

Comment: Got it :) This software is great but it will abort its search if it comes across a file in use by another program. You know anyway of fixing that? It goes for like 10 minutes finds a file in use by another program and than aborts the search

Comment: This is not a software issue, rather it's precaution measure. If it read a file already locked by any other program, it would be against OS policies and could lead to a system deadlock or failure of both the programs. You can ignore this just by closing all the other programs that could be using your files. :/ @Original-newbie

Comment: Yea I fured that but wasnt 100% sure. Anyhow thanks for the help. This will def give me a better chance on finding it. Wish I would have asked months ago. Just never did because i searched so long for a program that does what your program does. They really should put a donate to user button on this site.

Comment: It's ok, I'm out of a job, so if you ever need to hire a developer, consultant or a website deigner you can check me out. :) @Original-newbie

Comment: or if you just wanna donate something outta goodwill, then gimme your e-mail, I'll mail you my paypal ID. @Original-newbie

Comment: Sy fell asleep, how can i message you here on the site? I dont have enough reputation yet to chat with you (this is what the site told me) but if you know a way let me know. I prolly have work for you if you want it.

Comment: I meant, gimme your email address, and I'll mail you. haha :P @Original-newbie

Comment: i cant post my email on here..post urs :) n ill email u :)

Comment: got it...ill email u in a bit